# This is a question about the best type of regression analysis to use in my software

Tags: analysis, regression

Let me start by saying that I am not a mathematician and I am not very good at math.  I am mainly interested in obtaining the best possible results.

I am currently doing trial and error with my software and I am looking to save myself time and effort.  If there is anyone out there who is experienced in statistics and probability who can use his or her expertise to provide some advice on this matter, I would be very grateful.

> The software that I have provides the user with a choice of 4
>   different kinds of regression analysis.  They are as follows:
>
> - Exponential
> - Linear
> - Logarithmic
> - Polynomial
>
> I am trying to narrow down the possibilities.  Which type of analysis
>   would be the most likely to give the best results for generating
>   predictions as to a set of lottery numbers to use in a wheel for the
>   upcoming drawing and which ones of these 4 types are not likely to be
>   useful for generating good predictions.

The regression analysis is used to generate a chart called a LOWESS chart. LOWESS means Locally Weighted Scatter plot Smoothing Chart. The final part of the chart (on the right hand side) would be an extrapolation that would indicate what the next number or numbers would be for each ball position.

The software does this analysis and generates the resulting extrapolations by examining about 4 or 5 years of game drawing history. I am using this to try to beat Mass Cash (pick 5 from 35 game).

Thank you very much in advance.

Kosh

Answer (score 1):

Those four alternatives will return a function each, which fits a set of given data points.

This is not a good mathematical model for your problem.

What you might do is recording how often each number has been drawn, thus a historgram or frequency distribution. And then you might check, if in the case of many lottery drawings, if each possible lottery number has roughly the same number of occurences.